# Hiding rows according to imported cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to hide all rows which contain "no" in column L (12th). I try to make this script work each time my document is opened. The code is:

```
function onOpen(e){
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = sheet.getActiveRange();
  if (r.getColumnIndex() == 12 && r.getValue() == "no") {
    sheet.hideRows(r.getRowIndex(),1);
}
}
```

Unfortunately, the script doesn't work. Could someone explain me the problem, please?

**Important note! All values in column L are imported from another sheet via ImportRange function. I wonder if it's a problem...**

Answer (score 1):

When you first open a sheet, the event delivered to your onOpen trigger has no useful active range. The value `r.getColumnIndex()` will always be 1, because the active range is A1. (It's reporting which cell the user is in, and they haven't had a chance to move.)

Here's a way you could modify your function to do what you want. Note that it will only work on the first sheet in a multi-sheet spreadsheet.

```
function onOpen(e){
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getDataValues();
  // Check all rows except the first header row.
  for (var row = values.length-1; row > 0; row--) {
    // Check if the twelfth column contains "no"
    // Since arrays start at 0 but spreadsheet rows & columns
    // start at 1, we need to adjust by 1.
    if (values[row].length >= (12-1) && values[row][12-1] == "no") {
      // The data in column 12 of this row contains "no", so hide it.
      sheet.hideRows(row+1,1);
    }
  }
}
```